# How to scrap the text off of a message sent by a bot to another channel when reacted

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I am building a bot that allows users to message the bot then the bot sends the contents of the message to a moderation channel for approval. After approval, the message is sent to the public channel. My problem is in this last step. I cannot find a way to actually get the contents of the message as I haven't found anything in discord.js API that allows this.

So the bot sends the original message of the user to a moderation channel. The moderator either reacts with approve or reject.

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

  if (user === client.user) return;

  if (reaction.message.channel.id === moderationChannel) {

   if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌") {

    reaction.message.delete();

   } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
     
    let postMessage = new MessageEmbed() //the embed we send to channel
      .setAuthor(`Anonymous Confession`, interaction.guild.iconURL())
      .setDescription(messageContents)
      .setFooter(`Type "/confess" to send a confession`)
      .setTimestamp()
      client.channels.cache.get(publicChannel).send({ embeds: [postMessage] });
  }
  }

 });
```

previously I was able to directly pass the message of the user into the public channel using

```
let messageContents = messages.first().content
```

but this solution will not work here since there could be multiple messages that need approval and should be dealt with on an individual basis.

How should I pass the content of the approved message into `messageContents`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=content) property from [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message) object. So the code will be

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

  if (user === client.user) return;

  if (reaction.message.channel.id === moderationChannel) {

   if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌") {

    reaction.message.delete();

   } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
     
    let postMessage = new MessageEmbed() //the embed we send to channel
      .setAuthor(`Anonymous Confession`, interaction.guild.iconURL())
      .setDescription(reaction.message.content) // <---- get the message content from the reacted message
      .setFooter(`Type "/confess" to send a confession`)
      .setTimestamp()
      client.channels.cache.get(publicChannel).send({ embeds: [postMessage] });
  }
  }

 });
```

Hope it work!